# Incorrect warning from Python linter inside VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code, lint

I am struggling to understand why on VSCode the messages shown from the Linter still reference PyLint despite a different provider is used.

[image]

[image]

The curious thing is that if I do search the individual options for bandit in the setting json file, there is nothing, but if I did through the individual settings via the UI and then open the JSON file from there a separate - two lines - file is shown.

Somehow I don't think this is correct, as in fact the strange behaviour I'm experiencing.

JSON File below:

```
{
    "python.languageServer": "Pylance",
    "[python]": {
        "editor.formatOnType": true,
        "editor.defaultFormatter": "ms-python.python"
    },
    "python.formatting.provider": "black",
    "python.formatting.blackArgs": [
        "-t",
        "py37"
    ],
    "editor.fontSize": 14,
    "editor.formatOnPaste": true,
    "editor.snippetSuggestions": "top",
    "workbench.colorTheme": "Monokai",
    "editor.columnSelection": false,
    "files.autoSave": "afterDelay",
    "terminal.integrated.rendererType": "dom",
    "editor.renderWhitespace": "trailing",
    "git.autofetch": true,
    "editor.suggestSelection": "first",
    "vsintellicode.modify.editor.suggestSelection": "automaticallyOverrodeDefaultValue",
    "workbench.statusBar.visible": true,
    "editor.suggest.showStatusBar": true,
    "jupyter.alwaysTrustNotebooks": true,
    "python.autoComplete.addBrackets": true,
    "python.autoComplete.extraPaths": [
    
    ],
    "python.analysis.extraPaths": [],
    "python.analysis.completeFunctionParens": true,
    "workbench.editorAssociations": {
        "*.ipynb": "jupyter-notebook"
    },
    "security.workspace.trust.untrustedFiles": "open",
    "notebook.cellToolbarLocation": {
        "default": "right",
        "jupyter-notebook": "left"
    },
    "python.defaultInterpreterPath": "/home/andrea/.pyenv/versions/3.10.7/bin/python",
    "markdown.preview.openMarkdownLinks": "inEditor",
    "markdown-editor.useVscodeThemeColor": false,
    "explorer.confirmDelete": false,
    "git.suggestSmartCommit": false,
    "git.confirmSync": false,
    "jupyter.interactiveWindow.creationMode": "perFile",
    "python.linting.lintOnSave": false,
    "python.linting.enabled": true
}
```

Can somebody advice what how to setup correctly VSCode, please?

Comment: please show your relevant settings in JSON form. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/11107541